# ElasticSearch query referencing document

Tags: elasticsearch

I read some time ago that there was a way to build a query that references another document in your index. At the time, this wasn't helpful to me, but I now have very large GIS areas that I need to query against and sending this data to ElasticSearch in the query body every time seems wasteful.

While my specific use-case relates to GIS, `geo_shape`, etc, it's a general issue that can be applied to other types of queries.

I have a document type `areas` that holds all of the predefined search areas (these are things like suburbs, states, etc) and `entities` that hold all of my search data, including a [`geo_point` type](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-geo-point-type.html) field with lat/lon.

I need to be able to construct a [`geo_shape` query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-shape-query.html) for `entities` documents that references the `mpoly` attribute (which is a [`GeoShape` type](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-geo-shape-type.html)) on an `areas` document for it's shape coordinates.

Unfortunately, neither Google nor reading the ElasticSearch docs have proved useful in this case, because generally nested documents (related, but not what I'm looking for) is what people seem to be more interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer myself while looking for something different. Unfortunately, the information about the `GeoShape` filter is not in the `GeoShape` query manual pages:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-shape-filter.html#_pre_indexed_shape

```
{
    "filtered": {
        "query": {
            "match_all": {}
        },
        "filter": {
            "geo_shape": {
                "location": {
                    "indexed_shape": {
                        "id": "DEU",
                        "type": "countries",
                        "index": "shapes",
                        "path": "location"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone has better information about how to do this generically, I will happily accept their answer instead.